# My code runner in vs code is not generate output for JavaScript code and also I installed node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, output

I installed fresh vs code and did JavaScript in it. After that, I installed code runner for easy output but my code runner did not show me the output. I attached a screenshot of it.

And also I don't want in terminal output. I also checked and unchecked the terminal setting but it did not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A11kA.png)

Comment: save file or save those edits

Comment: Did you save your file? You need to save your file before running your code for your changes to take effect. (file > save) or control + s.